# I am unable to include mosquitto.h to c program on mac

Tags: c, macos, gcc, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to use mosquitto.h in my c program.
i installed mosquitto whit homebrew:
`brew install mosquitto`
but when i run:
`gcc mqtt_subscriber_01.c -o mqtt_subscriber_01 -lmosquitto`
i get:

```
mqtt_subscriber_01.c:4:10: fatal error: 'mosquitto.h' file not found
#include <mosquitto.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

i made Makefile:

```
CC = gcc

LIBS = -lmosquitto

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< 

make: mqtt_subscriber_01.c
    $(CC) -Wall -o test $^ $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
```

output of `make` is:

```
gcc -Wall -o test mqtt_subscriber_01.c -lmosquitto
mqtt_subscriber_01.c:4:10: fatal error: 'mosquitto.h' file not found
#include <mosquitto.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [make] Error 1
```

I am begginer to c and especialy to installing libararies.
my machine is mac m1 running ventura 13.3.1 (a) .
any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Where is `mosquitto.h` located? Maybe you need to add an include folder to your compilation command. I am not sure about MacOS but for Linux there are additional -dev versions of installable packages that are needed if you want to get the headers. Is there one for mosquitto, like mosquitto-dev?

Comment: apt has mosquitto-dev but homebrew unfortunately doesent